# Render custom menu filter icon

Tags: react-data-grid

Is there a way to render a custom icon for the column filter menu? I found the `prop renderMenuTool` (https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/api-reference#props-renderMenuTool) to render a custom column context menu icon, but I need a similar one for the filter menu icon.

I tried with prop `renderColumnFilterContextMenu`, but this one is just to customize the popup menu, not the Icon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is: `columns.filterEditorProps.renderSettings`.

See: https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/api-reference#props-columns-filterEditorProps-renderSettings